# Android textview center positioning

Tags: android, layout, textview, centering

I am trying to place 3 textviews in the center of the screen, with a bit of space between them since they are gonna be used as hyperlinks.

the result so far is:

[image]

and the code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:text="@string/about" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextTabletopRPG"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Tabletop RPG"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextDarkHeresy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Dark Heresy"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text40k"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:text="40k Universe"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you simply want the textviews to be centered horizontally as per the image example you provided you can do this:

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Test ME" />
```

If you want them to be in center of entire screen ie centered both vertically and horizontally without affecting the top paragraph you must wrap them in a seperate LinearLayout with property gravity set like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
```

Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:text="@string/about" />

    <!--wrap your centered textview with this-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

          <TextView
             android:id="@+id/TextTabletopRPG"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:text="Tabletop RPG"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Full Edit:** Try this for all centered in the view. You can change `android:gravity="center"` with `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` or `android:gravity="center_vertical"` on RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="@string/about" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextTabletopRPG"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Tabletop RPG"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextDarkHeresy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextTabletopRPG"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Dark Heresy"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text40k"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextDarkHeresy"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="40k Universe"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Note:** I added margin's for good display.

Comment: I meant the 3 textviews: tabletop RPG, dark heresy and lexicanum. to be in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

try adding:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
```

Comment: You can not write `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` to a `LinearLayout` member.

Comment: Rather use a Relative layout in anycase

Comment: the margintop works, but the android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  does not work

Comment: you can also add a table layout and put every TextView in a diffrent row

Comment: layout_centerHorizontal="true" only works for relative layout

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the  only one `textview` instead of another object try adding this:

```
android:id="@+id/emptyElement"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:text=""
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want there to be more space, you can use margins. Add this to each TextView's XML:

```
android:layout_margin="6dp"
```